# Why this data member is not accesible during upcasting?

Tags: java

I have a super and a sub class here , I'm trying to learn upcasting.

```
class Demo1{
    int x=10;

    void show(){
        System.out.println(this.x);
        System.out.println(this.s);
     }
}
```

and the Child class:

```
class Demo2 extends Demo1{

    int ashish=200;
    String s="Nana";

    public static void main(String... args){
        Demo1 d=new Demo2();
        d.show();
    }
}
```

Here, I'm trying to print `String s`. Why does it shows a compilation error that the variable doesn't exist?
By my knowledge, during upcasting .. the object instance created has all the data members of the child class and its reference is given to parent class variable, so why doesn't `this` referencing to the data members of Demo2?

Comment: This would fail to compile if there was no Demo2 class or 'upcast' - why? The *same* reason holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Demo1{
int x=10;

void show(){
    System.out.println(this.x);
    System.out.println(this.s);
 }
}
```

`Demo1` has to be able to exist as an independent unit.  If you created an instance of `Demo1`, by itself, it would not have any `s`, so this would be nonsensical.

What you *could* do, similar to what you're trying to do, would be something like

```
abstract class Demo1{
    int x=10;
    abstract String s();

    void show(){
       System.out.println(this.x);
       System.out.println(this.s());
    }
}
class Demo2 extends Demo1 {
    String s = "foo";
    public String s() { return s; }
}
```

This makes it explicit that `Demo1` has a "hole" -- an implementation detail subtypes need to fill in, to tell it how to get `s`.

Answer (score 0):

The super class doesn't know anything about the members (fields and methods) of any subclass. So, using the `s` field in super class is not allowed, thus you get the compiler error.